# Do wildcards exist for Firebase Fuctions on Storage?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-storage, google-cloud-functions

I've been using successfully Firebase Functions to perform operations on files I've been uploading to Firebase Storage.

What I currently want to do is access the folder into which I'm shoving data by using wildcards, with the same method of implementation as how it works for the Realtime Database + Firestore. However, whenever I try to access these parameters, they exclusively return `null`.

Is this not possible?

Here's an example of my code:

```
  exports.generateThumbnail = functions.storage.object('user-photos/{userId}/{publicOrPrivate}').onChange(event => {
    const privateOrPublic = event.params.publicOrPrivate;
    const isPrivate = (event.params.publicOrPrivate == "private");
    const userId = event.params.userId;

    console.log("user id and publicOrPrivate are", userId, privateOrPublic);
    //"user id and publicOrPrivate are undefined undefined"
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Based on [this documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/gcp-storage-events#detect_resourcestate_and_other_event_attributes), you can get the full file path in the bucket from the event:  `event.object.name`. You would then need to extract the path segments you want.  Have your tried that?

Comment: Thanks, but I have. I was hoping there could be a more elegant way to do so. I don't like parsing a string into an array, feels kinda hacky :<

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is currently no wildcard support for Cloud Storage triggers.  You have to check the path of the file that changed to figure out if you want to do anything with it.

Comment: Is this still the case in Aug 2019?